# as3 get WIDTH and HEIGHT of scaled / resized - movieClip / mc?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, height, width, scale

I am scaling a movieClip often and need to place it on the screen in certain places according to its size.

**Once scaled, how can I get the WIDTH and HEIGHT of a movie clip?**

```
trace(my_mc.width); /// would equal 333

/// This code makes my movie clip fit in the correct proportions. 
my_mc.height = stage.stageHeight;
my_mc.scaleX = my_mc.scaleY;

/// Its been resized!
trace(my_mc.width); /// STILL equals 333
```

..

**Any ideas how to get new width and height?**

Comment: Pasting this code in Flash shows width change - is this your actual code?

Comment: No its just an example. But the width does change with this code. Both height and width does. I didn't do the math. That is a great code bit from some smart Stack Overflower.

Comment: Thanks \`Papa\` I've been looking for `stage.stageWidth` and `stage.stageHeight` since I started Flash dev. *upvoted*

Answer (score 1):

You're probably experiencing stage scaling issues.

If you're dependent on stage size, set:

```
import flash.display.StageAlign;
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;

stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
```

Your provided example doesn't encapsulate the problem.  It works as expected.

[image: size scale]

Also possible is timing of your trace statements, if you're doing frame-based animation.  Perhaps you're viewing an artifact of size instead of in line with the lifecycle you expect.

Comment: Thanks Jason, I tried your code. I still get the same values with the trace.

Comment: Updating your question with actual implementation would help to isolate root cause.  Flash coordinate systems can become convoluted quickly.

Comment: Figured it out. Or a great work around. I hope this helps many people. I wish I would have discovered this years ago.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for all your effort. I found the answer! :)

---

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;

/// My stage is 500 by 500.
/// My Image or movieClip is 446 by 688.
/// I am calling it my_mc.
trace(my_mc.width + " by " + my_mc.height); /// OUTPUT: 446 by 688

// I want the height to match the height of my stage but keep the same 
// proportions. So I use the code below. WORKS GREAT!
my_mc.height = stage.stageHeight;
my_mc.scaleX = my_mc.scaleY;

// But if I want to trace the width and the height it will still be the same.
trace(my_mc.width + " by " + my_mc.height); /// OUTPUT: 446 by 688.


///So I make a NEW movieClip below after I scaled it.
var NewMC:MovieClip = my_mc as MovieClip; 

/// NOW WHEN I TRACE IT... :)
trace(NewMC.width + " by " + NewMC.height); /// 324.1 by 500

// YES!!! I can't believe I figured this out on my own! Woo hoo! :)
```

Comment: That makes no sense at all.  var NewMC:MovieClip = my_mc doesn't create a new MovieClip - it's a reference to the same instance, but it shows you probably have an issue with your instance names and variable scoping.